# How to create a User Login just for some action in CakePhp

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I have a website with CakePHP, I want to create a user login only for the Add, Edit and Delete for each model, ie, anyone can enter any part of the site, but for these three views one login is required.

Doing the beforeFilter for each view that I would give free access would require too much time and, ultimately, difficult to maintain.

There is a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In appController beforeFilter callback allow by default all actions:

```
// Allow all actions. CakePHP 2.0
$this->Auth->allow('*');

// Allow all actions. CakePHP 2.1
$this->Auth->allow();
```

Then in controller (or appController?) deny some of them:

```
parent::beforeFilter(); // Must be before deny method, in other way you first deny add and then allow it
$this->Auth->deny('add', 'edit');
```